# TCP request/response over a REST API

Tags: wso2-esb

Our application provides a REST API. However, a client can communicate only over TCP.
Is it possible in WSO2 ESB to make a proxy which would listen to TCP internally, then send the request to a REST API and send out the response as TCP?
The TCP request contains a message ID, which must be sent out in the response in order to be able to couple on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TCP transport receiver. Please refer the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/TCP+Transport) for more details